# Writting an image into folder in java project

Tags: java, directory

I am doing a java project in which im reading images from the folder in the project, but I cant write an image file into the same folder I get a exception like *resource not found*

I could use the image from a folder in project like:

```
jMenuItem1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imageselection/Images/open.png")));
```

when I try to write image into same folder like k is `BufferedImage`

```
 ImageIO.write( k, "jpg", new File("D:/pass.jpg"));
```

It works well, but when I write into

```
ImageIO.write( k, "jpg", new File("/imageselection/Images/open.png"));
```

it is not working.

"/imageselection/Images" is a folder in my project.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

```
ImageIO.write( k, "jpg", new File("./imageselection/Images/open.png"));
```

will work , you forget to add '.'

Comment: but it worked when i coded as     ImageIO.write( k, "jpg", new File("src/imageselection/Images/open.jpg"));

Answer (score 2):

If you use a getResource URL, the URL not necessarily is on the file system. If you compiled your application to a .jar file (zip format), then it is a file inside the jar zip. So for resources one cannot write.

A feasable solution is (for instance):

- Make an application data directory;
- Try first to find the image there as `File`;
- Otherwise load the image as resource;
- Write to the app data dir.

  ```
  File appDataDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/MyApp");
  appDataDir.mkdirs();
  ```